elasticesearchの集計queryについての質問
elasticesearchでの集計方法についてご助力願いたいです。
目的の結果を得るにはどのようにqueryを修正すれば良いでしょうか
以下はマッピングです。
{
  "test-aggs": {
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "app_name": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "data": {
          "properties": {
            "groups": {
              "type": "nested",
              "properties": {
                "keys": {
                  "type": "keyword"
                },
                "metrics": {
                  "properties": {
                    "cost": {
                      "type": "double"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "time_period": {
          "properties": {
            "end": {
              "type": "date",
              "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
            },
            "start": {
              "type": "date",
              "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

以下はindexに入っているデータです。
{
  "took": 9,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 2,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test-aggs",
        "_id": "SDWzbJMBYMg3fCn6fwuv",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "app_name": "test",
          "data": {
            "groups": [
              {
                "keys": [
                  "banana"
                ],
                "metrics": {
                  "cost": 0.1
                }
              },
              {
                "keys": [
                  "orange"
                ],
                "metrics": {
                  "cost": 0.2
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "time_period": {
            "start": "2024-10-01",
            "end": "2024-10-02"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test-aggs",
        "_id": "STWzbJMBYMg3fCn6fwuv",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "app_name": "test",
          "data": {
            "groups": [
              {
                "keys": [
                  "banana"
                ],
                "metrics": {
                  "cost": 0.5
                }
              },
              {
                "keys": [
                  "orange"
                ],
                "metrics": {
                  "cost": 0.2
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "time_period": {
            "start": "2024-10-02",
            "end": "2024-10-03"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

私が作成したqueryです
GET test-aggs/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "keys": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "data.groups"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "by_key": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "data.groups.keys"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "total_cost": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "data.groups.metrics.cost"
              }
            },
            "daily_costs": {
              "date_histogram": {
                "field": "time_period.start",
                "calendar_interval": "day",
                "format": "yyyy-MM-dd",
                "min_doc_count": 1
              },
              "aggs": {
                "cost": {
                  "sum": {
                    "field": "data.groups.metrics.cost"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 0,
  "sort": [],
  "_source": []
}

取得結果として期待していたのは以下のような構造です。
1 key別(bananaやorange)の料金の合計
2 key別(bananaやorange)の日別の料金
{
  "buckets": [
    {
      "key": "banana",
       total_cost": 0.6
       "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "2024-10-01"
            "cost": "0.1"
          },
          {
          "key": "2024-10-02"
          "cost": "0.5"
        }
       ]
    },
    {
      "key": "orange",
       total_cost": 0.4
       "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "2024-10-01"
            "cost": "0.2"
          },
          {
          "key": "2024-10-02"
          "cost": "0.2"
        }
       ]
    }
  ]
}

しかし返ってきたのは以下でした。
totalコストは正しいですが、日別のコストを得られませんでした。
{
  "took": 12,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 2,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "keys": {
      "doc_count": 4,
      "by_key": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "banana",
            "doc_count": 2,
            "total_cost": {
              "value": 0.6
            },
            "daily_costs": {
              "buckets": []
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "orange",
            "doc_count": 2,
            "total_cost": {
              "value": 0.4
            },
            "daily_costs": {
              "buckets": []
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}

